# boundedness of $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$ functions

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory

I was told that every function in the schwartz space is bounded, i.e.
If $f\in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$, then one can show $f$ is bounded by some $C$.

Could anyone show me the explicit calculation?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't this follow from definition? $f\in\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}) \iff \sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}}|x^jD^kf(x)|<\infty$ for all $j,k\in \mathbb{N}$. So in particular $j=k=0$ implies $f$ is bounded.

Comment: Yes. But explicitly, can we find a constant $C$?

Comment: The constant $C$ would be $\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}|f(x)|$, since it follows that $|f(x)|\leq C$ in this case. Do you mean how would you find the supremum?